# Google one tap renderButton pop-up events

Tags: google-api, google-signin, actions-on-google, google-one-tap

I'm using the google.accounts.id.renderButton() method with pop-up behavior.
When I click this button I get a pop-up opened.

Are there any onOpened and onClosed events I can subscribe to?